# node-canvas fail after updating node.js and Electron

Tags: node.js, canvas, build, electron

Windows 10, Electron app used to work great, using [node-canvas](http://github.com/Automattic/node-canvas) lib. Today, at long last updated:

npm -> 2.15.9

node -> 4.5.0

electron-prebuilt -> 1.4.1

then followed [instructions](http://github.com/Automattic/node-canvas/wiki/Installation---Windows) to update and rebuild the canvas lib. All dependencies updated, installed canvas@1.5.0  and `node-gyp rebuild` ran smoothly and successfully

But - running npm start to run the app fails with the following trace:

`App threw an error during load
Error: A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed.
\\?\D:\GoMixApp\web\electron\GoMixApp\node_modules\canvas\build\Release\canvas.node
    at Error (native)
    at process.module.(anonymous function) [as dlopen] (ELECTRON_ASAR.js:168:20)
    at Object.Module._extensions..node (module.js:583:18)
    at Object.module.(anonymous function) [as .node] (ELECTRON_ASAR.js:168:20)
    at Module.load (module.js:473:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:432:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:424:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:483:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\GoMixApp\web\electron\GoMixApp\node_modules\canvas\lib\bindings.js:3:18)`

Going back and forth for last few hours, I always end up with the same error. Am I doing something stupid?

Thanks

Comment: Are you rebuilding using one of the methods documented in http://electron.atom.io/docs/tutorial/using-native-node-modules/ ?

Comment: omg! I knew I was doing something stupid. I built against Node instead of Electron....Using `electron-rebuild` I got this solved but ran into https://github.com/electron/electron-rebuild/issues/15 so just uninstalled nslog... hopefully it wont come back to bite me. Thanks Vadim Macagon

Answer (score 0):

After installing the module, you need to run [electron-rebuild](https://github.com/electron/electron-rebuild)

```
npm install -g electron-rebuild
electron-rebuild -f -w canvas
```